# Aircon doesn't cool when car is stationary

Tags: ac, hyundai, tucson

I have a Hyundai Tucson. Recently I noticed the Aircon doesn't cool when the car is working and not moving. When I move for a few minutes Aircon starts to cool again.

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

If you rev the engine up and it starts to cool down, then you may be a little low on refrigerant.

If you really need to start moving, then the electric fans that are usually controlled by the a/c system may not be working.  They assist in cooling the condenser at the front of the engine bay, when there isn't sufficient air flow.

Comment: I really have to move and it is not even very cool like it used to be.

Comment: If you look in the engine bay while the air con is on, you should be able to see/hear the fans come on.

Comment: Ok. This is a good suggestion. I also start to see some condensation in the openings where the cold air comes. They are sticky, which suggest condensation in the Aircon piping.

Comment: That is not indicating a problem anywhere.